# how to GET the `id` of the specific data from previous page?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload, get

I have this form that will upload image for the specific person or data. But once I click the Upload button, the next page does not get the `id` from previous page. Why is that? Here is the code:

Here is the code for my form upload:

```
<form action="upload_photo.php?id=$id" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload Photo:
    <input type="file" name="image"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

and here is the code for the `upload_photo.php`:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["image"]["type"]);

        if (substr($imageType, 0,5) == "image") {
            $query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `image_name` = ?, `updated_photo` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $imageName, $imageData, $_GET['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


        }

        else {

            echo "Image not Uploaded!";

        }

}

?>
```

I tried to use `var_dump($_GET);` but the equivalent of `id` is `$id`
can someone help me please? thank you

Comment: what is the best way to do?

Comment: `$id => <?php echo $id ?>`

Comment: Why are you even appending it as a querystring - just chuck it in as a hidden form field : `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id; ?>" />` then it'll be available in `$_POST['id']`

Comment: As an aside, if you're using prepared statements you don't need to muck about with `mysqli_real_escape_string` - it'll be sorted out when you bind the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id like this:

```
<form action="upload_photo.php?id=<?php  echo $row1['id']?>">
```

Comment: what if im using mysqli prepared?

Comment: sorry...I haven't used mysqli prepared.